# Most efficient way to get elements of specific XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml, performance

What is the most efficiant way to get XML nodes of a specific parent each time?

Let's assume i have a XML that contains peoples' names, and each name node has favorite food's nodes and favorite drinks' node.
I have a system that let the user choose the people he want to get data for, and the system querying it by name and show it to the user after button click.

So is it better to split the main XML to xml for each person at the beginning of the program and then run just on the relevant person's xml, or maybe use `doc.GetElementsByTagName("food")` and `doc.GetElementsByTagName("drink")` by using some if\other conditions?

Thanks!!

XML example:
The user can choose "David" and get a list of his fave food and drinks, then choose John... etc.

```
<root>
  <David>
    <FAVE_FOOD>
      <food value = "hamburger"/>
      <food value = "banana"/>
    </FAVE_FOOD>
    <FAVE_Drinks>
      <drink value = "water"/>
    </FAVE_Drinks>
  </David>
  <John>
    <FAVE_FOOD>
      <food value = "icecream"/>
    </FAVE_FOOD>
    <FAVE_Drinks>
      <drink value = "7up"/>
    </FAVE_Drinks>
  </John>
etc...
</root>
```

Comment: Most efficient way is to store the xml tree in your own structure type, that uses a dictionary to store the root and it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to parse your XML with `XDocument`.

Here i created a custom function `GetUserData`. You need to pass `username` like `David` to this function and then this function can return you the list of food names and list of drink name.

Console app for demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Your path to xml");                //<= Load xml

        FoodData foodData = GetUserData(doc, "David");                      //<= Pass "David" to function

        foodData.FoodNames.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Food: " + x));   //<= Print food name list
        Console.WriteLine();
        foodData.DrinkNames.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Drink: " + x)); //<= Print drink name list

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static FoodData GetUserData(XDocument doc, string userName)
    {
        var data = doc.Root.Elements(userName).Elements();

        FoodData foodData = new FoodData
        {
            FoodNames = data.Where(x => x.Name == "FAVE_FOOD").Descendants().Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).ToList(),
            DrinkNames = data.Where(x => x.Name == "FAVE_Drinks").Descendants().Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).ToList()
        };

        return foodData;
    }
}

public class FoodData
{
    public List<string> FoodNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> DrinkNames { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to get all the food and drinks in one list (don't separate it to food list and drinks list).

Then simply get all food data and drink data into one list and return that list like

```
public static List<string> GetUserData(XDocument doc, string userName)
{
    List<string> data = doc.Root.Elements(userName).Elements().Elements().Select(x => x.Attribute("value").Value).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

And you can call above method like.

```
List<string> data = GetUserData(doc, "David");
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks for that! Is it efficient? I mean how long each name check operation should take (Let's say i have around 50-60 food and drinks values for each person).

Comment: let me check it with 100 foods and drinks. I'll update you in 5 min

Comment: i'd check with 100 foods and 100 drinks for `David` and it take only 2-4 miliseconds to fetch on my side :)

Comment: I rewrite `GetUserData` method to one more step to efficiency that we collect all the food data at once and then we apply filter to get food and drink names separately. plz view updated answer :)

Comment: if my answer was helpful to you then plz mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: another question: if i want to get all the food and drinks in one list (don't separate it to food list and drinks list), what should i do so i won't run twice?

Comment: answer updated plz view **Edit** section in answer :)

Comment: Thanks!! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I like using xml linq and putting into a dictionary with the key being the people names

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication83
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, object> dict = doc.Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => new
                {
                    drinks = y.Descendants("drink").Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("value")).ToList(),
                    foods = y.Descendants("food").Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("value")).ToList()
                })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => (object)y.FirstOrDefault());



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! And what will the value be.? object of what?

Comment: All the data put into a dictionary.